# How can I specify array parameter using Gnuplot command?

Tags: gnuplot

Specifically, I want to set xtics using several specific values through the `-e` option, as like how we specify a parameter

```
gnuplot -e "param=1" script.gnuplot
```

But it returns the following error,

```
gnuplot -e "myxtics='(2,4,7,16)'" script.gnuplot

set xtics myxtics
                 ^
"script.gnuplot", line 58: increment must be positive
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get gnuplot to explicitly handle the variable as a macro, so that it is expanded in the `set` command line as the very first thing. Just prefix the variable with `@`:

```
set xtics @myxtics
```